# Connection between span & consistency AND that of linear independence & unique solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

I was going through Linear Algebra videos and just had an idea which is mentioned below.

In matrix equation $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ (System of linear equations), we know that $\vec{x}$ will exist (Solution will exist) only if $\vec{b}$ lies in the span of columns of $A$. {connection between SPAN and CONSISTENCY}

Taking $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ to be consistent, if columns of $A$ are linearly independent of each other, the system will have **unique solution**.
Otherwise if columns of $A$ are not linearly independent, the system will have **infinitely many solutions**. {connection between LINEAR INDEPENDENCE and UNIQUE SOLUTION}

Will it maybe somehow work? First one is a fact but I am not sure about the second connection